# AWS DLT: Saving Data to File

Tags: amazon-web-services, jmeter

I'm currently running my performance tests on AWS DLT using JMeter scripts. I have defined in the JMeter script, a BeanShell post processor that will append a variable to "./results/customer_ids.txt". I've ran this locally on my machine and it seems to work fine, however I can't seem to get DLT to save this file into the S3 bucket, here is the post processor code below:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage;
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;
String testPlanFile = GuiPackage.getInstance().getTestPlanFile();
String testPlanFileDir = FilenameUtils.getFullPathNoEndSeparator(testPlanFile);
vars.put("testPlanFileDir", testPlanFileDir);
log.info("testPlanFileDir:" + testPlanFileDir);

id = vars.get("customer_id");

log.info("This is the customer id:" + id);

f = new FileOutputStream(vars.get("testPlanFileDir")+"/results/customer_ids.txt", true);
p = new PrintStream(f);
this.interpreter.setOut(p);
print(id);

f.close();
```

Anyone have any idea how I could get it to properly save to the S3 bucket? As it works on my local machine... figuring it must be an issue with the file path, as I have had to include these apache libraries to get it to save to the correct location on my local machine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think only limited subset of [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) results files is getting uploaded, you can check this out yourself [here](https://github.com/aws-solutions/distributed-load-testing-on-aws/blob/main/deployment/ecr/distributed-load-testing-on-aws-load-tester/load-test.sh#L117-L121)

```
echo "Uploading results, bzt log, and JMeter log, out, and err files"
aws s3 cp /tmp/artifacts/results.xml s3://$S3_BUCKET/results/${TEST_ID}/${PREFIX}-${UUID}-${AWS_REGION}.xml
aws s3 cp /tmp/artifacts/bzt.log s3://$S3_BUCKET/results/${TEST_ID}/bzt-${PREFIX}-${UUID}-${AWS_REGION}.log
aws s3 cp /tmp/artifacts/jmeter.log s3://$S3_BUCKET/results/${TEST_ID}/jmeter-${PREFIX}-${UUID}-${AWS_REGION}.log
aws s3 cp /tmp/artifacts/jmeter.out s3://$S3_BUCKET/results/${TEST_ID}/jmeter-${PREFIX}-${UUID}-${AWS_REGION}.out
aws s3 cp /tmp/artifacts/jmeter.err s3://$S3_BUCKET/results/${TEST_ID}/jmeter-${PREFIX}-${UUID}-${AWS_REGION}.err
```

So you can [create your custom build](https://github.com/aws-solutions/distributed-load-testing-on-aws?tab=readme-ov-file#creating-a-custom-build) which will upload your custom data as well. Alternatively you can go for [AWS SDK for Java](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/) and upload your file directly, code examples [are available](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example_s3_PutObject_section.html)

And last but not the least, [using Beanshell is some form of a performance anti-pattern](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting), consider migrating to [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy).